# GLBCX not found when importing TVM

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, tvm

I am really new to compilers. I have installed the TVM following the instructions on the [site](https://tvm.apache.org/docs/install/from_source.html). However, when I type the command:

```
python -c "import tvm"
```

I see this error:

```
OSError: /home/maryam/anaconda3/envs/tvm-build/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/maryam/tvm/python/tvm/libtvm.so)
```

I have tried installing libgcc, but it didn't help. Also, I have checked pythonpath, and the version in the apache-tvm folder is already included.

I would appreciate it if anyone helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by entering

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6"
```

after installation in the terminal.